# Error "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm attempting to use CMake to build an open source C++ project (https://github.com/google-deepmind/mujoco_mpc/tree/main), but I encountered an error.

```
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe - broken
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
[cmake]   The C compiler
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   It fails with the following output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Change Dir: 'C:/Users/PC/Code/mujoco_mpc-main/mujoco_mpc-main/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-z9zhya'
[cmake]     
[cmake]     Run Build Command(s): C:/msys64/usr/bin/ninja.exe -v cmTC_599f8
[cmake]     [1/2] C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cc.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_599f8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c 'C:/Users/PC/Code/mujoco_mpc-main/mujoco_mpc-main/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-z9zhya/testCCompiler.c'
[cmake]     FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_599f8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj 
[cmake]     C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cc.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_599f8.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c 'C:/Users/PC/Code/mujoco_mpc-main/mujoco_mpc-main/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-z9zhya/testCCompiler.c'
[cmake]     /bin/sh: line 1: C:msys64ucrt64bincc.exe: command not found
[cmake]     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It states that "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe" is unable to compile a basic test program. I've tried various solutions I found on the internet, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is my enviroment variables:

```
C:\Users\PC>cc --version
cc (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Users\PC>where cc
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cc.exe

C:\Users\PC>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\msys2_shell.cmd -c;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Comment: How do you provide your compiler's path to cmake? You can see the path is wrongly parsed in the log. Could you provide your CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: `/bin/sh: line 1: C:msys64ucrt64bincc.exe: command not found` ... backslashes - You need to replace your backslashes with `/`

Comment: I didn't paste anything. This is an open-source project. I cloned the source code, and a CMake pop-up appeared. I simply clicked to set it up

Comment: @19020051PhạmTrungNghĩa The open source project isn't prepared for the backslashes in paths that Windows uses.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My bad. I haven't used Windows for a period of time. I remembered to use doubled backsplashes in path. But I come to realize that's in programming with escape character.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But one thing is sure that the backslashes in the path is somehow omitted, which is really strange

Comment: @LiuYuan Not really. In `sh` language they are illegal escape sequences so `sh` is "helpful" and just ignores the backslashes, leaving an invalid path as a result. A path containing `foo\new` would contain a valid escape sequence: `foo` _newline_ `ew`.

Comment: @19020051PhạmTrungNghĩa I found a [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/849) with the same error you have, does this fits your requirement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255482/discussion-between-liuyuan-and-ted-lyngmo).

Comment: @19020051PhạmTrungNghĩa I suggest that, if you can't make it work using the `mingw` version of `ninja` that the issue LiuYuan  linked to suggests, you open an issue in the open source project. It states _"We have not tested MJPC on Windows, but there should be no issues in principle."_ - and this is where you can help by providing the output you got when trying to build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully configured it with Ninja of Mingw64. I still don't understand why it had issues with Ninja of Urs. But in the end, everything is fine now

Comment: What's Urs?....